# Run eval `ssh-agent -s` gives errors

Tags: ssh, exec, puppet, puppetlabs-apache

Trying to run the command  **eval `ssh-agent -s** with the command option puppet which gives me these error:

```
exec { 'eval' :
        command => "eval `ssh-agent -s`",
     }
```

Gives me this error:

```
Error: Validation of Exec[eval] failed: 'eval `ssh-agent -s`' is not qualified and no path was specified. Please qualify the command or specify a path. at /puppet.pp:18
    Wrapped exception:
'eval `ssh-agent -s`' is not qualified and no path was specified. Please qualify the command or specify a path.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to setup PATH for you [exec](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/type.html#exec-attribute-path). I can be defined locally, by setting path parameter :

```
exec { 'eval' :
        command => "eval `ssh-agent -s`",
        path => [ '/bin/', '/sbin/' , '/usr/bin/', '/usr/sbin/' ],
     }
```

or globally:

```
Exec { path => [ '/bin/', '/sbin/' , '/usr/bin/', '/usr/sbin/' ] }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use fully qualified path.

For example either:

```
exec { "sample":
  command => "/usr/bin/test",
}
```

or:

```
exec { "sample":
  path    => ['/usr/bin', '/usr/sbin', '/bin'],
  command => "test",
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your approach is flawed.

It is not possible to manipulate the Puppet agent's environment by running commands through `exec` resources. Each such resource forks a subprocess that is independent, with the main environment remaining immutable.

**Update:** The best approach to allow Puppet to run with an `ssh-agent` depends on how you start the Puppet agent. For example, if you use `/etc/init.d/puppet start`, you will want to change this init script to wrap the Puppet process in an `ssh-agent` directly. If you run from `cron`, change the job to run `ssh-agent` etc.

Comment: The votes are "appreciated", some commentary would be even better.

Comment: I voted you up, but here is some commentary: your answer is correct, but not very useful. What is the solution you propose?

Comment: @jbass that's fair. Thanks!